# What are the benefits of high testosterone in men?

Tags: endocrinology, lifestyle, benefits, testosterone, male

It's common to hear about products that claim to be testosterone boosters for men and vitamins that boost testosterone, but what benefits does high testosterone actually entail? For example, are physical strength, libido, and mental capacity increased? Mental health discussion would be interesting too, if there's any association.

Comment: Higher testosterone levels can't be achieved with so-called boosters, as explained in [this answer](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/906/natural-testosterone-booster-intakes?rq=1), so you might consider editing your first sentence.

Comment: [So, the Kali Muscle diet doesn't work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOOVwbOFL8s)

Comment: @CountIblis I recommend asking that as a separate question. It would be a good one to address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **What are the benefits of high testosterone in men?**
>
> what benefits does high testosterone actually entail?
>
> Mental health discussion would be interesting too, if there's any
>   association

### Suggested Introduction

I think it is important to recognize that levels of the [testosterone hormone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testosterone) in the male body decrease naturally in men with age.

The level of this hormone peaks in young men starting sometime after puberty, but usually in the late teenage or early twenty age range. Typically the level of this hormone in men starts to decrease between the ages of 30 - 40 or so, and at a slow rate; generally around one percent a year.

> [**What happens to testosterone levels with age? <sub>(1)</sub>**](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/sexual-health/in-depth/testosterone-therapy/art-20045728)
>
> Testosterone levels generally peaks during adolescence and early
>   adulthood. As you get older, your testosterone level gradually
>   declines — typically about 1 percent a year after age 30 or 40. <sub>(1)</sub>

### Testosterone Effects (physical and mental)

As far as high testosterone levels and its benefits are concerned, I'll give a general breakdown of typical effects (physical and mental) but I will allow you to classify these as beneficial or not depending on your perspective of these effects.

**Physical Associations with High Testosterone**

High levels of testosterone starting in early adulthood contribute to puberty transformations in the male body such as: genital organ growth, sexual maturity and fertility, growth of body and facial hair, and deepening of the voice. Higher levels of testosterone are also associated with *but not limited to* increased metabolism (burn fat faster), increased muscle mass, strength, and bone density.

> [**What is testosterone? <sub>(1)</sub>**](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/sexual-health/in-depth/testosterone-therapy/art-20045728)
>
> Testosterone is a hormone produced primarily in the testicles.
>
> Testosterone helps maintain men's:
>
> - Bone density
> - Fat distribution
> - Muscle strength and mass
> - Facial and body hair
> - Red blood cell production
> - Sex drive
> - Sperm production

**Mental Associations with High Testosterone**

High levels of testosterone is associated with *but not limited to* more aggressiveness and the effects of such behavior such as feeling more competitive. It also contributes to sleeping better and feeling well-rested, having more energy, increase in sexual desire and libido, heightened focus and concentration, and more self confidence and motivation.

> [**Central Nervous System <sub>(2)</sub>**](http://www.healthline.com/health/low-testosterone/effects-on-body#Central-Nervous-System)
>
> [image]
>
> The body has a system for controlling testosterone, sending messages
>   through hormones and chemicals that are released into the bloodstream.
>   In the brain, the hypothalamus tells the pituitary gland how much
>   testosterone is needed, and the pituitary relays that information to
>   the testicles. <sub>(2)</sub>
>
> Testosterone plays a role in certain behaviors, including aggression
>   and dominance. It also helps to spark competitiveness and boost
>   self-esteem. Just as sexual activity can affect testosterone levels,
>   taking part in competitive activities can cause a man’s testosterone
>   levels to rise or fall. Low testosterone may result in a loss of
>   confidence and lack of motivation. It can also lower a man’s ability
>   to concentrate or cause feelings of sadness. Low testosterone can
>   cause sleep disturbances and lack of energy. <sub>(2)</sub>
>
> It’s important to note, however, that testosterone is only one factor
>   that influences personality traits. Other biological and environmental
>   factors are also involved. <sub>(2)</sub>

---

### References

- [**Testosterone therapy: Potential benefits and risks as you age (1)**](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/sexual-health/in-depth/testosterone-therapy/art-20045728)

  - [**Meet the Mayo Clinic Staff**](http://www.mayoclinic.org/about-this-site/meet-our-medical-editors)
- [**The Effects of Testosterone on the Body (2)**](http://www.healthline.com/health/low-testosterone/effects-on-body#Central-Nervous-System)

  - [**Meet the Healthline Staff**](http://www.healthline.com/health/about-us)

Comment: Do testosterone levels decline primarily as a function of age or does it depend primarily on things like exercise intensity, fitness and muscle mass which tends to decline as we age? So, if someone aged 50 is exercising much harder,  has much better fitness level and has way more muscle mass than when he was 35, will his testosterone level still be a lot lower than what it was when he was 35?

Comment: @CountIblis, Again, I recommend asking these as separate questions. Fish, you interpreted the question correctly. I only mentioned boosters as an introduction/background to the question.