# What are the benefits of estrogen in women?

Tags: benefits, testosterone, estrogen, female

I've commonly heard that symmetrical to testosterone benefits in men ([What are the benefits of high testosterone in men?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/what-are-the-benefits-of-high-testosterone-in-men)), estrogen contributes health benefits to women. What are they?

Comment: I don't feel that "volumes" can be written about estrogen's benefits. Additionally, this question opens up discussion to more specific questions once it's addressed, i.e. "Since estrogen does X in women, should Y do Z?" or etc.